# Error while running Logistic Regression in pyspark mlib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pyspark

I am having a dataframe(df_ml_nullable), like this :

```
+-----+--------------------+
|label|            features|
+-----+--------------------+
|  0.0|[127.0,132.0,123....|
|  0.0|[67.0,67.0,67.0,6...|
|  0.0|[-29.0,-30.0,-28....|
|  4.0|[31.0,31.0,31.0,3...|
|  0.0|[39.0,40.0,42.0,4...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Below is the schema of this data frame:
df_ml_nullable.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- label: double (nullable = false)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = false)
```

I try to run the logistic regression like this :

```
    from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
    from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
    lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
    (train_d,test_d)=df_ml_nullable.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
    model1 = lr.fit(train_d)
```

When I try to run this I get this error : 
**IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct,values:array> but was actually struct,values:array>.'**

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: You should check what vector type you are using. Depending on your Spark version there can be a conflict between spark.mllibs and spark.ml, if you use the regression of one package with the vector type of the other package you get this error.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks a lot for the reply. The feature column was originally a double array ( output of a collect_list operation). I converted it to a vector using the udf below:
`def fn(row):
    ln = len(row)
    idx = range(ln)
    sp_vc = Vectors.sparse(ln,idx,row)
    return(Vectors.dense(row))
    #return(sp_vc)
usr_fn = F.udf(fn,VectorUDT())
df_indexed_vct = df_indexed.withColumn("features",usr_fn(F.col('pump_sequence')))`
So in the return type of udf should i use a different vector type?
A silly question - how do I check the version of spark.ml and spark.mlib in my environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the import. Instead of importing from ml I was importing the vectors from mllib. The below correction did the trick:

```
#from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors,VectorUDT
```

@ Vincent - Thanks for the hint.